# "Interactive review" of hunks during git rebase

Tags: git

I have a list of commits, that I want to apply some final changes to before merging:

```
- A1 Add doc for widget
- A2 Fix error in foo#process
- A3 Add spurious new lines
...
- An ...
```

I would like to:

- Edit the contents of some commits
- Drop some commits
- Accept some commits

This looks like a job for `git rebase -i`, but there are quite a number of commits and I am not 100% sure they are all "hygienic" (that is, that the commit message exactly covers the changes). I don't want to drop anything by accident.

Is there a process in git that will basically show me each commit in turn with its staged hunks and let me "Ok commit" "Wait, edit, commit" or "drop"?

Setting all the commits to "edit" just drops me into a state where `git status` shows no changes, meaning I have to diff with the previous commit, reset, edit, etc. It is quite tedious.

Basically I want a sequential series of prompts that show the git tree "just before" the commit was made, with a dirty tree.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what "edit" means in an interactive rebase? Just mark them all "edit". You can hunkify further by resetting one step, inspecting the work tree, and even doing an interactive add.

Comment: Edit leaves me with a clean tree, perhaps that is the only way with manually `git reset HEAD~1;  git diff / git add -p` each time.

Comment: It also makes "dropping" harder? I would have to commit no changes or reword the commit to "drop this" then repeat the rebase dropping the marked commits.

Comment: I don't have what I would call a *good* answer to this: I think this is a job that *should* be tedious, at least if you want to be meticulous. You'll see this same tedious (and meticulous) process occur on the Git mailing list, as proposed changes to Git get worked and reworked and rewritten and resubmitted: "patch v8, 17/59" etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `git rebase` with the `--exec` flag

You can use `git rebase` with `--exec` to automatically reset to the prior commit at each interactive rebase step:

```sh
git rebase --exec "git reset --soft head^" <your other rebase args go here>
```

How this works:

1. The `reset head^` will roll `head` back to the prior commit at each step.
2. The `--soft` flag results in the index not being rolled back, so the changes from the current commit will be staged and ready for you to commit or amend as you wish.
3. Because the `reset head^` results in an index with uncommitted changes, the interactive rebase will stop at each step, just as if you changed all of the `pick`s to `edit`s in the todo file.

You can leave off the `--soft` if you would rather manually re-add the changes to the index at each step.

Comment: But this is just an automatic version of what I already said. It doesn't resolve the OP's objection that it makes `drop` harder after the pause.

Comment: automatic is the point ("there are quite a number of commits"). This achieves what is requested in the last para, though the "prompt" is a regular shell prompt and they would have to use normal git commands -- which is also an upside because they can do all sorts of stuff besides "edit, commit or drop", including splitting commits, partial commits, etc.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this answer satisfies _me_. I'm just saying I don't think it meets the OPs goal. Probably nothing can.

Comment: it's the best i could come up with, though there might be a reliable third party tool, e.g. like how third-party git-filter-repo is recommended by the git maintainers over standard git-filter-branch.

Comment: @markson-edwardson did you ever try this?